# watir a string value is depriciated Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, webscarab

> Warn Watir [Depreciation] using the :class locator to locate multiple
>   classes with a string value is deprecated. Use array instead

i get this error while running this line

```
browser.button(:class => '_t38eb _ov9ai').click
```

which i think is one class not multiple classes i tried this as mention in the warring

```
browser.button(:class => ['_t38eb','_ov9ai']).click
```

but the page freezes then terminate
the web i'm trying to scarab is Instagram here trying to log in the page after filling the username and password field

and if i write this the chromedriver terminates

```
browser.button(:class == '_t38eb _ov9ai').click
```

Comment: Class names are separated by whitespace, so `_t38eb _ov9ai` denotes _two_ classes, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Chrome driver and Firefox Driver while you automate, Your browser is closing because chrome driver closes the browser once after the execution of your code but Firefox driver doesn't closes the browser. If you want to keep your chrome browser open, then use this code

```
require 'watir'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: {detach: true})
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

The given below code doesn't work

```
browser.button(:class == '_t38eb _ov9ai').click
```

That's because `button()` method need Hash Object not the object of `TrueClass` or `FalseClass` which you are passing while you write `:class == '_t38eb _ov9ai'`

If you want to pass an array, you may better use [#split:](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split)

```
browser.button(:class => '_t38eb _ov9ai'.split).click
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: `Watir` is open source.

[This line](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/78ef6ad343c7d00bd5647d1563bb5f5abb30190c/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder/xpath.rb#L52) is the source of the deprecation warning.

The reason for this deprecation is to build the more idiomatic xpath with [`contains(this) and contains(that)`](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/78ef6ad343c7d00bd5647d1563bb5f5abb30190c/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder/xpath.rb#L104).

I am not sure why it's freezing, but I am positive it’s completely safe to ignore the warning.